# I cannot import components in React

Tags: reactjs, import, components

Hi guys this is my App file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import test2 from './test2';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <test2 />;
  }
}
export default App;
```

and this is my test2 component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class test2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>hello</div>;
  }
}
export default test2;
```

but for some reason I cannot see it in my app component,
does anyone see the error? 
this is what I get:
'test2' is declared but its value is never read. [6133]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a linter warning. With JSX, custom component "tags" must start with a capital letter. Lower case tag names are treated as strings.

```
<test2 />
```

is equivalent to

```
React.createElement("test2", null);
```

I.e. this will pass the string value `"test2"`, not resolve to the variable `test2`.

You want

```
import Test2 from '...';
// ...
<Test2 />
```

which is equivalent to

```
React.createElement(Test2, null);
```

See [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) for more info.

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Components Should be names starting with capital letters else it will be considered as html tags like h2. p etc...

```
class Test2 extends Component {
 render() {
   return <div>hello</div>;
}
}
```

export default Test2;